# Pop up reveal modal dialog when submit by using ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb-Foundation Reveal Modal in Rails.

I want to open a new modal dialog when a submit button is pushed and show confirmation infos.

With a link like this, the modal open without problem.

```
<a data-remote="true" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-type="html" href="/foo">Link</a>
```

But with a form and submit, the modal doesn't appear.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/foo" data-remote="true" data-type="html" method="get">
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"></div>
  <input id="bar" name="bar" type="text" value="bar">
  <input id="my-submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I've take `data-reveal-id="myModal"` away, because if this exists, submit itself doesn't work.

And coffee script for it. `show modal` appears in console, when `submit` is clicked.

```
$ ->
 $('#my-submit').on(
    click: ->
      console.log("show modal")
      $('#myModal').trigger('click')
```

When I replace `trigger('click')` to `reveal()', then I get this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'reveal'

I've followed a answer from [this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/foundation-framework-/p9PdeqgBuKU).

How can I show result of submit in modal dialog?

Comment: I haven't looked at the Reveal Modal from Zurb, but it looks like the modal is depending on the `data` attribute you have set in the first example called `data-reveal-id`. I don't see that anywhere in your second example.

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? I don't see how you use the ajax response in your code. Seem the ajax part is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `reveal()` or `trigger('click')`, I should have used `foundation('reveal', 'open')`

```
$ ->
 $('#my-submit').on(
    click: ->
      $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open')
```

With this code works fine now.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation on the Zurb Foundation site](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html#), you need to have a data attribute called `data-reveal-id` on the object that should reveal the modal when clicked.

So you should try something like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/foo" data-remote="true" data-type="html" method="get">
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"></div>
  <input id="bar" name="bar" type="text" value="bar">
  <input id="my-submit" data-reveal-id="myModal" name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**EDIT**

I think I misunderstood your question. If you want the dialog to appear once the submission was successful, then you'll probably need to use jQuery's `ajax` functions.

You could try something like this in your javascript.

```
// formId is the id of your form
$('#formId').submit(function (e) {
    var url = $(this).attr('action');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: $('#formId').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $('#myModal').reveal();
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This would call the `reveal` function once the AJAX request has completed. If you need to display information that the server generated, the `data` parameter that's passed to the success callback function will contain whatever data the server responded with.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained it. With `data-reveal-id` form itself doesn't work.

Comment: I updated my answer. Take a look and see if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer Zajn! I tried your code but it doesn't work also. But I finally found the cause of error. I should have call `foundation('reveal','open')` function, not `reveal()'.

Comment: Okay, glad you figured it out. You should post your solution as an answer and accept it!

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is this as zurb foundation just need the ID of modal in data-reveal-id attribute

```
input id="my-submit" data-reveal-id="myModal" name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an in-line solution with jQuery:
add the following option to your reveal mechanism (`<a>,<input>,` etc).

```
onClick="$('#'+$(this).attr('data-reveal-id')).foundation('reveal', 'open');"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just written a reusable snippet which I'll share here in case it's useful to anyone else who is trying to get the result of a form submission over ajax using reveal.

Note that I have used data-form-reveal-id instead of data-reveal-id to avoid foundation hooking up the form's click event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form[data-form-reveal-id]').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);

    var $reveal = $('#' + $this.data('form-reveal-id'));
    $reveal.foundation('reveal', 'open', {
      url: $this.attr('action'),
      method: $this.attr('method') || 'GET',
      data: $this.serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        alert('modal data loaded');
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('failed loading modal');
      }
    });
  });
});
```